# Passing variable from event handler

Tags: matlab

I would be very grateful for help, advice or suggestion. I have an application to control geodetic instrument using synchoronous interface. However some commands are asynchronous by its nature, e.g. `GetReflectors`. After this command is triggered I receive as many server answers as is the number of available reflectors. So I have registered an COM event and associate handler function. So far so good. I can display the data coming but I do not know how to pass some variable to the main function. I tried to save variable as .mat file or in .txt file and read it. Actually it works in Matlab but it does not works in compiled .exe aplication (Error firing event). Even `disp` command does not work in compiled aplication (display nothing). So the main question is: how to pass variables from handler to main function. Is there a way? Global variables? Thank you Filip

Edit: I am adding an code to demostrate the problem... I need to save Reflector Name and Reflector ID so as the user can choose one (because there are multiple events coming with different Reflectors).

```
function pushbutton_GetReflectors_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
ltsync = actxserver ('LTControl.LTCommandSync2');        %Act as server: LTConnect2
ltsync.events()                                          %List of all COM events
ltsync.registerevent({'ReflectorsData' 'ReflectorsHandler'}) %Register event
ltsync.GetReflectors()                                %Ask instrument for reflectors
pause(3)                                                   %Time to receive answers
end

function ReflectorsHandler(varargin)    %Handler of the event ReflectorsData
%var1,var2,reflectorID,reflectorName,var5,surfaceOffset,reflectorsTotal,var8,var9
disp('Reflector Data:');
disp(varargin{3})        %Reflector ID
disp(varargin{4})        %Reflector name 
end
```

Comment: Is this purely in MATLAB? If so, I believe you can do this by deriving a class from `event.EventData`, and I will post an example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve this problem by passing a function handle to `registerevent` instead of just the string function name, and creating a class to allow you to pass the data back. First, the class:

```
classdef ReflectorsResponse < handle
    properties (SetAccess = private)
        reflectors
        responseComplete = false;
        reflectorsTotal = NaN;
    end

    methods
        function respond(obj, varargin)
            % Create a struct for each reflector (or you could define
            % another class, but let's keep it simple for the time being)
            newRefl = struct();
            newRefl.ID = varargin{3};
            newRefl.name = varargin{4};
            newRefl.surfaceOffset = varargin{6};
            % ... store other properties in struct
            % Store this reflector
            obj.reflectors = [obj.reflectors; newRefl];

            % Store total reflector count and check for completion
            if isnan(obj.reflectorsTotal)
                obj.reflectorsTotal = varargin{7};
            end

            if length(obj.reflectors) == obj.reflectorsTotal
                obj.responseComplete = true;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

You can then use this by making the `respond` method your handler:

```
function pushbutton_GetReflectors_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
    % Create the response object and associated handler function handle
    response = ReflectorsResponse();
    handlerFun = @(varargin)response.respond(varargin{:});

    ltsync = actxserver ('LTControl.LTCommandSync2');        %Act as server: LTConnect2
    ltsync.events()                                          %List of all COM events
    ltsync.registerevent({'ReflectorsData' handlerFun}) %Register event
    ltsync.GetReflectors()                                %Ask instrument for reflectors

    % Wait for request to complete
    while ~response.responseComplete
        pause(0.1);
        drawnow update;
        % NOTE: Should add a timeout to this loop
    end

    % Do stuff with response.reflectors
end
```

This will wait until there has been a response for each of the reflectors, the number of which is determined from the first response. Note that you should add a timeout to the `while` loop, otherwise you risk waiting infinitely.

If there are lots of these asynchronous requests that you have to handle, I would suggest encapsulating the entire request/response sequence (including the creation of the ActiveX server, setup of the event handler, and waiting for the response(s)) in a generalised base class, and deriving specific subclasses for each different request.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure if you understand. I can´t edit the event because it is defined by the LTControl.dll. So inputs of the handler are only given by instrument answer. I have added an short simplyfied example above.

Comment: @user2397310 Answer updated; hopefully this should work, but if there are any problems please let me know - obviously I can't test it fully as I don't have that COM component (or any reflectors).

Comment: Great, this looks very good. Unfortunately I cant test it now either, I will have the instrument at the earliest on Friday. I will let you now. Thank you for now, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: Finally, I have figured it out. It was all about missing function containing event hadler in compiled .exe file. I stated: "%#function ReflectorsHandler" and it works like a charm. Matlab did not compiled it before because it was stated only in string (registerevent). Thank you for your help!